# Following up 'however' (complete sentence) with another 'however' (or similar)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Take for example this passage:

> I am very skilled at building websites. However, I am unable to demonstrate these websites as they are used internally by my previous company, and I no longer possess valid credentials. **However**, I can present to you snapshots of the websites.

Instead of the doubled up 'however' what would also be an appropriate alternative word? Nevertheless seems good, but I also use that as a beginning later in the paragraph. Any other appropriate alternatives?

Comment: *Despite that*?

Comment: Do you even need the first 'however'?

Comment: @Glorfindel It's applicable, but I don't feel like it rolls off the tongue as well

Comment: @GoatsWearHats I've actually worded it differently in my actual passage where the However sounds more fluidly

Answer (score 2):

> I am very skilled at building websites, ***and while*** I am unable to demonstrate ***private, internal*** websites, I can present snapshots of ***those*** websites.

Answer (score 1):

try synonyms for either however or nevertheless: nonetheless, all the same, even so, notwithstanding, still, yet...
you could even say "but I can present to you..."

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both sentences. I know it would be a bit lengthy but that will be fine I guess. Decide if you can go with it.

"Although I am unable to demonstrate these websites as they are used internally by my previous company and I no longer possess valid credentials, I can present to you snapshots of the websites."

Best Regards!

Comment: Yeah that actually sounds pretty good